# Multiple IF functions in one Excel cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

So another Excel question, regarding `IF` functions. I would like to include multiple `IF` functions in one Excel cell but keep getting the value error.

```
=IF(E18 >= 24, E29 - E31 + G68)/E18 IF(E18 >= 36, E29 - E31 + G69) / E18
```

grateful for any help! Thanks

Comment: Could you explain your logic? The formula contains two separate `IF`s which is incorrect.

Comment: Have a look at `AND` and `OR` formulas

Comment: I would like to use the same formula but use a different cell value when a different number of months is inputed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in comment, it's little bit unclear what you are after, but I think you need this:

```
=IF(E18 >= 36, (E29 - E31 + G69) / E18, IF(E18 >= 24, (E29 - E31 + G68) / E18))
```

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you're only changing the `G68`/`G69` reference based on the value in `E18`.

Place the number 24 in cell `F68` and 36 in cell `F69`.  The formula `VLOOKUP($E$18,$F$68:$G$69,2,TRUE)` will then return the correct value from column `G`.

- 24 to 35 will retun the value in in `G68`.
- 36 and above will return the value in `G69`.

Using this you can shorten your formula to:

```
=E29-E31+VLOOKUP($E$18,$F$68:$G$69,2,TRUE)/$E$18
```

or

```
=SUM(E29,-E31,VLOOKUP($E$18,$F$68:$G$69,2,TRUE))/$E$18
```

**Edit:**  Sorry, updated formula - forgot to divide at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Place all the formulas inside the opening and closing parenthesis and separate the functions with `,` —a comma.

The reason why you're getting an error is because you're not using the correct syntax. Syntax is like the structure of a formula, like grammar in languages.

Correct syntax:

`IF(logical_test, value_if_true, [value_if_false])`[1](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)

Try this formula:

`=IF(E18>=24,(E29-E31+G68)/E18,IF(E18>=36,(E29-E31+G69)/E18))`

or possibly a better formula like this:

`=IF(E18>=24,E29-E31+G68,IF(E18>=36,E29-E31+G69))/E18`

or if you're using Office 365:

`=IFS(E18>=24,E29-E31+G68,E18>=36,E29-E31+G69)/E18`

You may also add some sort of a catcher in case your conditions fail such as:

`=IF(E18>=24,(E29-E31+G68)/E18,IF(E18>=36,(E29-E31+G69)/E18,"NO MATCH"))`

`=IFS(E18>=24,(E29-E31+G68)/E18,E18>=36,(E29-E31+G69)/E18,TRUE,"NO MATCH")`

I hope this helps..

References:

[IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)